# eBook reader for Android that allows the import of DRM protected EPUB eBooks

Tags: android, pdf, ebooks, epub

I love and hate the [Kobo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kobobooks.android) app for Android. I love it because it's simple and I can easily connect it to my Kobo account and download my purchases. I hate it because the import of external eBooks sucks (can't choose the folder, slow etc.) and because the overall speed of the app is a bit slower than I want it to be.

When looking for an alternative, my number one concern is that I won't be able to have my purchased books in the same app and I don't care to switch apps. I know I can remove the DRM from them, but in all honesty, there should be an easier way than that.

I am looking for an Android app that will:

- Easily allow me to import DRM eBooks into the app (via an Adobe DRM file).

  - I must be able to login to Adobe DRM (Adobe ID) in order for Kobo to authenticate the book I wish to add to my device.
- While importing external eBooks, I must be able to choose the folder and select the files you wish to import. Selecting external storage is a good thing to have, but not a must.

  - Must be able to import EPUB and PDF files. Other file formats are optional.
- Should do what a eReader is supposed to do:

  - Display book covers
  - Display book titles
  - Sort by author or title
  - Add bookmarks, and notes
  - etc.
- Preferably gratis (free), but not required .

Comment: I don't use "Digital Restriction Management" stuff myself. But if you want to check some alternatives to Aldiko (good choice, btw), you can take a look at [eBook Reader](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=75) – which lists a lot of eBook readers, and also features a matrix comparing them. The "DRM" column there is what you should pay attention to then :)

Comment: @Izzy Nice website you got there! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad you like it! New feature launching soon: articles (how-tos and the like, not the "daily blog" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aldiko](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android) sounds like it'll fit your requirements. Aldiko has two versions, a free version and a paid version. The difference between the two is that the free version is ad supported and the paid version has highlights (for EPUB files), notes (for EPUB files) and home widget features.

**Features:**

- PDF, and EPUB support
- Support for Adobe DRM books (and you can sign into Adobe DRM using an Adobe ID)
- Can import your own eBooks by selecting the folder you wish to copy the eBooks from. From my experience, this runs quite a bit faster than Kobo's scanner.
- All the customization features that an eBook reader should have:

  - Displays book covers, titles
  - Can sort by author or title
  - Can add notes in the paid version of the Aldiko
  - Bookmarks
  - Table of content support (click on a page and it will jump to that page)
  - Adjust font size
  - Adjust font type and background colours
  - Alignment and line spacing options
  - Brightness controls
  - A dictionary

**Screenshots:**

Recent reads

[image: Recent reads]

Library

[image: Library]

Customization options

[image: Customization options]

Comment: Wow. That's how an ebook reader should look like!!! If i compare the iBooks app I become so jealous...